# deny access to all subdirectories using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have web structure like this:

```
root
    folder1
    folder2
    errors
    resouces
    ...
    index.php
```

and I want to deny access to all subdirectories exept errors. I don't want to have .htaccess in every single subdirectory, just one in root. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an environment variable if the request contains a `/errors`, doing something like this in your htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /errors iserrors=1
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=iserrors
```